# Enable MIC in genymotion / Any other good android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, audio-recording, genymotion

I am making a app that use mic to record audio.

How can I enable mic in genymotion emulator?

or

Is there any other good emulator for android app dev?

need help
Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Genymotion can actually use your computer's microphone.
Depending on your computer it sometimes does not work because of VirtualBox hardward support.

Here is a conversation about this topic on the [Genymotion's Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/genymotion-users/iXIWUDTcj1w).
You should try to play with the sound configuration on VirtualBox:

- Open VirtualBox
- Choose a VM and open its settings
- Go to sound tab and change the audio controler or audio pilot

Let me know what is your configuration (OS, Genymotion version).

Comment: Thanks for your response!
I tried changing all audio controls but no effect I also read the google group that says you can use mic only in linux or mac it do not work on windows.

Comment: I am listening sounds coming out of my virtual device but not able to make it listen to the mic. :/ What sort of configuration required for that?

Comment: `Genymotion` can record voice from computer `mic`  **BUT** recorded was a chopped sound

Answer (score 1):

This emulator does not support microphone if you are using windows host OS.

Genymotion developers are aware of this, they even filled a virtualbox bug.